# Inheriting from uitableviewcontroller crashes app

Tags: ios, xcode

I dragged a view controller into my app then created a new view and made it segue to that view. I created a class for that view and made it inherit from uitableviewcontroller but when I segue to that view the app crashes terminating with uncaught exception of type nsexception. Is this because the view is not a table view controller? Or am I missing something else? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "embedded it in another view"? How did you do that?

Comment: sorry i did not mean that i fixed my error

Comment: You should drag a new UITableViewController if you want that in storyboard instead of UIViewController. If you inherit from UITableViewController, make sure you have base view as UITableView and have delegate and datasource connected.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it crashes because the tableViewController expects its root view to be a tableview and you embedded the tableview in another view